# How to retain the curves after plotting in R Shiny?

Tags: r, shiny, r-plotly

I am building a Shiny app, where the user can add different curves to the plot, but I can't make the plot to retain the already added curves. How can I make that happen?

In the simplified reproducible code below are altogether 8 curve possibilities, based on 3 radiobuttons selections which have 2 options each. I would like to keep these as radiobuttons and not use checkboxes, as in my real app that I am working on there will be about 300 combinations that would be too confusing to use with checkboxes. Please see the code below:

```
library(shiny)
library(plotly)
library(dplyr)

data111 <-data.frame("x"=1:10, "y"=c(99,98,97,96,95,94,93,92,91,90))
data112 <-data.frame("x"=5:14, "y"=c(79,78,77,76,75,74,73,72,71,70))
data121 <-data.frame("x"=9:18, "y"=c(59,58,57,56,55,54,53,52,51,50))
data122 <-data.frame("x"=3:12, "y"=c(49,48,47,46,45,44,43,42,41,40))
data211 <-data.frame("x"=7:16, "y"=c(29,28,27,26,25,24,23,22,21,20))
data212 <-data.frame("x"=11:20, "y"=c(19,18,17,16,15,14,13,12,11,10))
data221 <-data.frame("x"=2:11, "y"=c(95,94,93,92,91,90,89,88,87,86))
data222 <-data.frame("x"=1:10, "y"=c(45,44,43,42,41,40,39,38,37,36))

ui <- fluidPage(
titlePanel("Curve selection"),
sidebarLayout(
  sidebarPanel(

     radioButtons(inputId = "option",
                 label="Choose the option",
                 choices=c("option1"=1,
                           "option2"=2),
                 selected = 1),

     radioButtons(inputId = "type",
                  label="Choose the type",
                  choices=c("type1"=1,
                            "type2"=2),
                  selected = 1),

     radioButtons(inputId = "group",
                  label="Choose the group",
                  choices=c("group1"=1,
                            "group2"=2),
                  selected = 1),

     actionButton("add","Add curve to the plot")
  ),

  mainPanel(
    plotlyOutput("plot")
  )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {

data <- eventReactive(input$add,{
 get(paste0("data",input$option,input$type, input$group))

})

output$plot <- renderPlotly({

 data <- data()

 p <-plot_ly(type = "scatter", mode="lines")
 p<-add_data(p, data) %>% add_trace(p, x= ~x, y = ~y)
 p

})
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

I expect that the user can choose the option, type and group in the radiobutton selections, then add the curve. After that, make a new selection of option, type and group and add the new curve to the already existing one in the plot. The user should be able to do this several times. Do you know how this can be achived?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to use a `reactiveValues` object, in which you save already added traces.

Then you can use `add_trace` with a for loop for example:

I changed your `eventReactive` to an `observeEvent`, which appends the new data to the `reactiveValues` list.

To prevent plotting the same object twice, I created a reactiveValues `usedData` object, which will save the plot legend names. If the name is already at hand, nothing will be added to the plot.

```
server <- function(input, output) {

  d <- reactiveValues(a=NULL, name=NULL)
  usedData <- reactiveValues(d = NULL)

  data <- observeEvent(input$add,{
    src = paste0("data",input$option,input$type, input$group)
    var <- get(src)

    if (src %in% usedData$d) {
      print("Data is already plotted")
      req(F)
    }

    if (is.null(d$a)) {
      d$a <- list(var)
      d$name = list(src)
      usedData$d <- src
    } else {
      d$a <- append(d$a, list(var))
      d$name = append(d$name, list(src))
      usedData$d <- append(usedData$d, src)
    }
  })

  output$plot <- renderPlotly({
    req(d$a)
    data <- d$a
    names = d$name

    p <- plot_ly(data = data[[1]], type = "scatter", mode="lines")

    if (length(data) == 1) {
      p <- add_trace(p, x= ~x, y = ~y, name = names)
    } else {  
      for (i in 1:length(data)) {
        d <- data[[i]]
        p <- add_trace(p, data = d, x= ~x, y = ~y, type = "scatter", mode="lines", name = names[[i]])
      }
    }
    p
  })
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the solution,  works as intended! 

Could you please help me out with the following minor adjustment: I noticed that if the user presses the "add" button several times without changing anything in the radiobuttions then a new legend will be added to the plot. This could cause that there are for example 3 curves but 4 labels in the graph. Do you have any suggestion how to solve this? 

Would you also have a solution on have to add legends that correspond to the input selections (input$option,input$type, input$group) instead of the "trace" for the curves?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: If you press "add" button several times without changing any of the options, then a line AND a new legend entry will be created. But since the line will be identical to the previous one, it will not be visible in the plot and only in the legend. I'll edit my answer to show correct legend names and prevent double plotting.

Comment: Thanks a lot SeGa, I checked the answer, but could not upvote due to the lack of reputation points.

Comment: No problem, you'll get there soon ;)

Comment: Hi SeGa! I could transfer the code you generously provided to my real app, however I encountered a new problem which I cannot solve unfortunately. Do you maybe have a suggestion how to avoid adding legends to the plot when the chosen combination of selection does not pull any data in because that combination of data set is missing)? So the problem is that while no new plot is added to the existing ones, a legend of the selection appears on the plot. I tried setting "src" to NULL with if conditions but it does not work. Would you have a solution to this? Thanks!